# Scan and readLines

Tags: r, function

In R, `scan` and `readLines` have same function on file reading, but different classes of output. To get the vector for further steps, I use `scan` in reading files. However, one of the text file always occurs error, just like below:

```
filt <- "E:/lexicon/wenku_baidu_com/stopwords_cn.txt"
specialfilter <- scan(file = filt, what=character(), nmax = -1, sep = "\n", blank.lines.skip = TRUE, skipNul = TRUE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
Read 1 item
Warning message:
In scan(file = filt, what = character(), nmax = -1, sep = "\n",  :
  invalid input found on input connection 'E:/lexicon/wenku_baidu_com/stopwords_cn.txt'
```

The environment has checked several times, no directory error, no encoding error(file encoding is UTF-8). The salient feature in this file is it has thousand of lines. If use `readLines`, there is no errors at all:

```
specialfilter<-readLines(filt, encoding = "UTF-8", skipNul = FALSE)
```

My questions are:

1. Is `scan` have lines limits on reading files? If the answer is
   “yes”, how many lines it can read in one file?
2. If in this case, we can only use `readLines`, how to change the
   result(specialfilter) into vector?

PS: the file uploaded in a network storage, its only 12kb: https://yunpan.cn/OcMTMXyFXNQzYu  Access Code is `3c9d`

Comment: The output of `sessionInfo()` might help as that file read in fine with that `scan()` configuration for me. But for #2: `rl <- readLines("stopwords_cn.txt") ; identical(rl, specialfilter) ; ## [1] TRUE`

Comment: As far as I know, "sessionInfo()" is a function which helps to check up the infomation of other packages. However, "scan()" is not a package. How do you use "sessionInfo()" to help file reading with "scan()"?

Comment: @赵鸿丰 what he means is that `sessionInfo` would help *us* to find out what is going on, since this error does not occur for us. The output of `sessionInfo` may show something peculiar about your setup, that perhaps causes the error. Also, it doesn't just check other packages, but also your OS, version of R etc.

Comment: My sessionInfo() is:
`R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8.1 x64 (build 9600)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                              
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base`
Though I first run this function on a Windows7 PC, but the result are the same, the file can not be read.

Comment: improved formatting